# Reverting several bad commits, but preserving a good commit in between

Tags: git, version-control, github

My tree looks like this:

```
A --> B --> C --> D --> E
```

*A* is good commit,
*B, D, E* are wrong merges,
*C* is a good commit.

So I need to keep A and C, and get rid of others.
Is there a nice way to do that?
Thanks in advance to all Git-ninjas.

Comment: `git checkout -B master A; git cherry-pick C` if you haven't pushed.

Answer (score 1):

in git, reverting a commit only undoes that commit, not the full series leading to it, so you just need to:

```
git revert E
git revert D
git revert B
```

Now I notice that you specified that those commits were merges, so you'll need to specify the parent that you want to keep, so use the `-m parentNumber` flag:

```
# revert the E commit, keeping the state of the first parent
git revert -m 1 E
# (and similar for the others...)
```

ie. look at the following commit graph:

```
-------R--S--M
-P--Q-------/
```

Here we have two 'branches' that got merged in `M`. If you tell git to revert `M`, it does not know if you want to keep the code in the state of commit `S` or in the state of commit `Q`, so you need to tell git which parent of the merge do you want.

```
git commit -m 1 M  # will leave you in commit S
git commit -m 2 M  # will leave you in commit Q
```

Comment: That gives me a message 'B is a merge but no -m option was given.'

Comment: Should I merge everything again if I do that? Because the other guy was merging all that...

Comment: yes, if you revert it, you will have to merge it again. You might find [Linus' reverting a faulty merge](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) an interesting read regarding merges and reverts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git cherry-pick` for that.

Answer (score 0):

If the commits are "pushed" (public) you should revert doing either of:

1) as many reverts as there are bad commits:

```
git revert E
git revert D
git revert B
```

2) You can commit a single revert by doing this:

```
  git checkout B -b temp
  git rebase -i A
```

Edit file to keep only the commits you want to revert and squash the remaining into a single commit.

```
  git revert <that single commit>

  git checkout E
  git cherry-pick <revert from that single commit>
```

then you need to edit the commit message so that it make sense in your original E branch.

However, if the commits are local and never were published, you should remove them instead for a cleaner tree.

```
  git checkout B -b temp
  git rebase -i A
```

Edit file to keep only the commits you want.